# After the playstore update I'm no longer able to use my Play Store credit from my Google Rewards app

Tags: google-play-store

I have $6 in my [google rewards app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.paidtasks&hl=en_US) sitting there and there's a button on the app to take me to the app store. When I click on a premium app the option to pay for it with the rewards balance does not appear.

Has anyone else seen this issue? I am using a pixel 3. The balance also shows in my Google Pay app as well. I have been able to do this in the past no problem.

Comment: Which "rewards app" are you talking about (please add name and play store link)?

Comment: @Robert updated